# need label for flatButton

Tags: dart, flutter

So I have a flatButton widget with an asset image as the child. I would like to append a label to the bottom of it, but I don't know how.

```
Expanded(
              child: FlatButton(
                child: Image.asset('images/boy.png'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context, _PageTwo());
                },
              ),
            )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the child property a `Column`. How does this work for you?

Column class docs: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html

```
Expanded(
  child: FlatButton(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Image.asset('images/boy.png'),
        Text('I am a label')
      ]
    )
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.push(context, _PageTwo());
    },
  ),
)
```

Comment: That actually worked perfectly. Keeps the text aligned with the images just like a label.Thank you so much.

Comment: No worries. The Column widget is super useful. Glad it worked!